# \s escape in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, escaping

Working with regular expressions in Eclipse, I accidentally forgot to double escape the `\s` special character. Surprisingly, Eclipse didn't refuse to compile my code. Even this line (which has nothing to do with regular expressions) compiles and runs successfully:

```
System.out.println("a\sb");
```

In contrast, standard JDK compiler gives an error saying that `\s` is an illegal escape character, as expected.

So what is the meaning of this "improvement" in Eclipse? What are other "extended" escape characters? I couldn't find any official documentation on this.

Comment: Eclipse itself doesn't compile anything. Which compiler is it using and which other compiler refuses to compile that code?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca As far as I know, Eclipse has its own compiler. I also tested this code with Oracle's JDK 8 and JDK 11 compilers and they work as expected.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I use Eclipse IDE for Java Developers, Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)

Comment: @JohnMcClane - It appears to be a bug in the version of Eclipse that you are using. The best course of action would be to report the bug.

Comment: Could not reproduce this issue for Eclipse version 2020-03 (4.15.0), the compile-time error `Invalid escape sequence` is displayed.

Comment: Actually `\s` is a valid escape sequence in [text blocks](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/378), which are new for Java 15 and which have been in a preview state for a while now.  Whether `\s` will be allowed in regular single-line String literals, I don’t know.